# How to get value from bootstrap datepicker and pass it to compare data stored database

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I want to get value from datepicker (only on change without using any button), and compare this date with stored database. My project is for orders and every order has a date, so I want to view old or new orders depending on their dates. Also when opening the website, it should display the current date (today) with its orders. Here's my code:

```
<input class="datepicker" name="datepicker"  id="datepicker" />

<script> //date picker js

$(function() {               
  $("#datepicker" ).datepicker({

    dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',

  });
});
</script>


$q_customer = $conn->query("SELECT * from orders inner JOIN 
        customer_order on customer_order.order_no 
        =orders.order_no inner join driver_order  on 
        driver_order.order_no=orders.order_no LEFT JOIN 
        customer on customer.phone=customer_order.phone 
        order by k_time" ) or die(mysqli_error());

$k_time = '';

while($f_customer = $q_customer->fetch_array()){?>

<tr>
<?php

if($k_time == '' || $k_time != $f_customer['k_time']){
  $k_time = $f_customer['k_time'];

  echo "<td>".$f_customer['k_time']."</td>";

} else{
  echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
}
?>

<td><?php echo $f_customer['order_no']?></td>
<td><?php echo $f_customer['first_name']?></td>
<td><?php echo $f_customer['last_name']?></td>
<td><?php echo $f_customer['address']?></td>
<td><?php echo $f_customer['driver_no']?></td>
<td><?php echo $f_customer['d_time']?></td>
<td><?php echo $f_customer['no_ofppl']?></td>
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
```

You can also set this as a variable or if you want to get the date by selecting the day then try this.

```js
$('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function(e) {
  var date = e.date;
});
```

Althought you need to change the format of the date.